# SSRS Report tablix - wrap 2 columns on page, with group page break

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a report requirement to print tablix rows in two columns per page. The Customer group needs to page break to a new page. If the customer has enough records it will wrap on the same page into two columns.

I was able to get a solution working by specifying Report columns property as “2”, and fiddling with the page/tablix sizes. I added page break and the next customer goes to Column2 instead of next page.

Is there a way to add two page breaks to force the group to the next page? I tried added more page breaks on the rectangle object holding the customer text boxes. But it still goes to Column2; Instead of adding 2 page breaks it only add 1 page break. Is there something I can do to get next customer on the actual next page instead of Column2?

---

**Property - Report Page columns.jpg**

[image]

1 customer - 2 columns.jpg ** **GOOD** **

[image]

2 customers - 2 columns.jpg ** **WRONG** **

[image]

Comment: If you don;t get anywhere with this then you may want to consider using a subreport. Your report works fine for 1 customer so you could just call it repeatedly as a subreport for all customers. It might be less painful to resolve. Just a thought....

Comment: Thanks for the idea. How could I use a sub report to get the 2 columns wrapping tablix?

Comment: Your current report works OK for a single customer I believe? So create a new report with a dataset that just has a list of customers in, then add a tablix bound to this dataset. In the tablix, insert a subreport and point it to your existing report, passing the customer ID (for exmaple) as the parameter. If you don;t understand, let me know tell me what parameters your current report takes so I can mock something up.